# Taxes for EU/EEA/CH working for a few days in another member country

Tags: taxes, eu, spain, switzerland

I'm an EU/EEA/CH living and working in another country in the block, with a local contract for a local company. Due to the covid situation I am allowed to work remotely for as much as I want as long as it doesn't generate any tax issues for my employer, so I want to take advantage and work from my home country from time to time.

The only information I can find is that you are considered a tax resident if you spend more than 180 days per year, but I don't know what's the limit for generating taxes elsewhere.

I would prefer this to be a generic question, but if it matters I'm Spanish living in Switzerland and working for a Swiss company, wanting to work remotely from Spain for my Swiss employer for a few weeks.